# Eth private chain sent transaction to smartcontract error "Transaction has been reverted by the EVM"

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

I'm newbie and now in progress for develop some smartcontract use on ethereum private chain.

I have created KeepPolicy.sol for keep policy data to blockchain, and have dapp for call method in KeepPolicy.sol.

The problem is I got error message in response when call the method. The error message is

> {
> "message": "Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:\n{\n  "blockHash": "0x11378a4cdaa39bf77b68d8a522d6f337eb897182f6110844e4b6b0b6ea14ef54",\n  "blockNumber": 4349,\n  "contractAddress": null,\n  "cumulativeGasUsed": 23144,\n  "effectiveGasPrice": 0,\n  "from": "0x2013291683023bae332f1e47d378f50265c3d88e",\n  "gasUsed": 23144,\n  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",\n  "status": false,\n  "to": "0xd16ea25805abf4e6defad30e6669fe68dd176aed",\n  "transactionHash": "0xaab5b843ba14d2a4ff63a1a91e64f4fed7bbbdee8c7f13870d2f6132155f8d4a",\n  "transactionIndex": 0,\n  "type": "0x0",\n  "events": {}\n}"
> }

and i have some related code here.

*send transaction, call setPolicy*

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    contract.methods.setPolicy(hashId, hashHospitalString, encHospitalString, encPub).send({ from: admin, gas: 100000 })
    .then(function (receipt) {
        if (receipt) {
            console.log('transaction receipt', receipt)
            resolve(receipt)
        }
        resolve({result: false})
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return reject(err)
    })
})
```

*KeepPolicy.sol*

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract KeepPolicy {

    struct Policy {
        string hashId;
        string hashHospitalString;
        string encHospitalString;
        string encPub;
    }

    uint256 countId;
    mapping (uint256 => Policy) public policies;

    receive() external payable {}

    function setPolicy(string memory _hashId, string memory _hashHospitalString, string memory _encHospitalString, string memory _encPub)
    external payable {
        uint256 count = countId++;
        policies[count].hashId = _hashId;
        policies[count].hashHospitalString = _hashHospitalString;
        policies[count].encHospitalString = _encHospitalString;
        policies[count].encPub = _encPub;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post code snippets as text so it's easier for answerers to copy-paste and test in their local environment. You can find more useful tips in the [tour] page.

Answer (score 1):

I close this issue, the problem is about problem when deploy smart contract.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The function is payable. Please try to add value argument to your transaction or remove payable from the contract. E.g.: `.send({ from: admin, gas: 100000, value: 0 })`